# Using Javascript in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get an html form to grab a value from a javascript code. I'd like for the hidden field "SubID" to grab the value of the javascript function. This is what I have so far.. what am I doing wrong:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset><input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" /></fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="SubID" value="uid1">
<fieldset><button id="contact-submit" name="submit" type="submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button></fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getCookie(name)
  {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
  }
  var uid1 = document.write(getCookie("uid"));
</script>
```

Comment: I firstly advice heavily against cookies. Easy to manipulate if not done correctly, leading to security exploits.

Answer (score 2):

Add a listener to the submit event of the form:

```
// declare listener
function handleSubmit() {
    var myHiddenInput = document.querySelector('[name=SubID]');
    myHiddenInput.value = getCookie("uid");
}
// hook listener to the event of the form
var myForm = document.querySelector('form');
myForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit, false);
```

That should work in the latest browsers. If you need to support older browsers, the `.addEventListener()` changes a little.

More on [how to add simple event listeners here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Add_a_simple_listener).

Demo in [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/fifotenebe/edit?html,output) or below:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
  var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
  var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
  return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
//var uid1 = document.write(getCookie("uid"));

var myForm = document.querySelector('form');

function handleSubmit() {
  var myHiddenInput = document.querySelector('[name=SubID]');
  // myHiddenInput.value = getCookie("uid");
  myHiddenInput.value = "test -- have a look at the network tab to check if this was submitted";
}
myForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit, false);
```

```html
<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <fieldset><input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" /></fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" name="SubID" value="uid1">
  <fieldset>
  <button id="contact-submit" name="submit" type="submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: just a comment more than anything - above is fine but remove the inline js and move to a `<script>` - inline js is bad practice and leads to hard-to-maintain code, even if it's just for easy answering to show what to do, people new to coding will see it and start getting into a habit of inline js which.. well is terrible :) but otherwise +1

Comment: Please don't advocate inline HTML event attributes. Separate the JavaScript from the HTML and use the DOM standard `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs @ScottMarcus Thanks for the kind input. In my experience, newbies don't get much the `.addEventListener()` strategy when they don't know a lot about events. But I'm just a bit low on faith these days. You are right, since this is a mostly educative environment, we should strive to show the correct way. (In other places we could start with the inline while saying that was not the optimal way, but that would be unfeasible here, since people copy&paste most of the code anyway.) Cheers!!

Comment: I would really advise against showing inline event attributes, ever. They aren't just syntactically inferior. There are real, tangible reasons why they can cause the code to operate incorrectly. They are a thing of the past. Let's let them go and never speak of them again. `.addEventListener()` is the correct and standard approach. Newbies need to learn that.

Comment: +1 for the adjustment to `.addEventListener()`. Now, could you include your code snippet here, rather than providing a link to an external site as those links can become dead over time?

Comment: @acdcjunior thanks, I tried it adding that code the way it's laid out in JSBin, and for some reason subID still shows "uid1" instead of whats in the cookie.

Comment: @mcfattyfats If you set a hardcoded string to the `.value` of the hidden input, do you see it being sent?

Comment: @acdcjunior it's not posting whats in the "myHiddenInput.value" even when I change it to a hardcoded string, just what is in the value which is "uid1".

Comment: I changed the sample code, added a debug `action`, which allows you to see what was posted. Try clicking submit on the code snippet at the answer. You should see the hardcoded string. Do you see it?

Comment: @acdcjunior thanks again you've been extremely helpful. I kept trying it out and it kept outputting uid1 but I ran it through my code editor and it finally outputted the correct code. So it looks like the code works, but not within wordpress for some reason. Currently using visual composer and the inputting the code into the "raw html" widget and running into that same error.

Comment: Can you place a `console.log('something');` at the `handleSubmit` to check if it is being called?